# ordinary question: choosing balls from urn, confuse about the "ordering"

Tags: probability

I am confuse about the ordering for the probability question.

*Say we have $5$ red, $4$ blue balls, and we pick $3$ balls, what is the probability that $2$ of them are red?*
My solution:

$$\binom{3}{2} \times (5/9) \times (4/8) \times (4/7)$$

because you can choose Red`Blue`Red, or RedRed`blue` , or `Blue`RedRed

*Another question, a hand of $5$ cards, what is the probability that you have $2$ ace and $1$ jack.*
             My solution:

$$\binom{5}{2}\times (4/52)\times (3/51)\times (4/50)$$

Do you guys think this is correct?

---

Update:

I always get confuse about the probability questions of these kinds. For instance the first question about "choose balls from urn". There are usually two ways to solve question like this: 1) treat each drawn as seperate trial, 2)use combinatorics.  The reason I got confuse because in the first method, you need to account for orderings of RBR or BRR etc. But in the second method, sometimes you don't need to do that. This confusion always annoy me.

Comment: The one about cards is not right. We need to deal with the other cards in the hand of $5$. The standard way would be $\binom{4}{2}\binom{4}{1}\binom{44}{2}$ divided by $\binom{52}{5}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do it in the style you are using, proceed as follows. We first find the probability of Ace, then Ace, then Jack, then two cards which are neither Ace nor Jack (I am assuming that by $2$ Aces and $1$ Jack you mean exactly $2$ Aces and exactly $1$ Jack.)

The probability of getting Ace then Ace then Jack then two extra cards is then 
$$\frac{4}{52}\cdot\frac{3}{51}\cdot \frac{4}{50}\cdot \frac{44}{49}\cdot \frac{43}{48}.\tag{1}$$

But there are many other orders in which we could get these cards. How many? The $2$ Aces can be placed in $\binom{5}{2}$ ways. For each of these ways, the remaining $3$ cards can be placed in $3!$ ways. The probability is therefore  the number in (1) times $\binom{5}{2}3!$.

**Another way:** There are $\binom{52}{5}$ **equally likely** ways to choose $5$ cards.

There are $\binom{4}{2}\binom{4}{1}\binom{44}{2}$ ways to choose a hand of $2$ Aces, $1$ Jack, and $2$ extra cards. So the probability is
$$\frac{\binom{4}{2}\binom{4}{1}\binom{44}{2}}{\binom{52}{5}}.$$

Comment: can you please look at my update?

Comment: The first question was done correctly, so I did not comment on it, though I would use $\frac{\binom{5}{2}\binom{4}{1}}{\binom{9}{3}}$, which leads to the same number. In the second question, your analysis was partly right, you just did not deal with the $2$ "useless" cards. Your analysis in both cases took account of ordering, which is fine as long as you compensate by multiplying by the total number of orderings. Which is best tends to vary from problem to problem.